# Java 8 get all elements in list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of Objects where each object that returns `List<String>`.
How can I use Java 8 streams to get only one `List<String>`?

`Contact` class has the following method;

```
public List<String> getSharedFriendsIds() {
    return sharedFriendsIds;
}
```

And I have

```
List<Contact> contactsList;
```

What I was trying was

```
List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
    .map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds)
    .sequential()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But above line is not returning  `List<String>` but rather  `List<List<String>>` which is not what I want.

Comment: Why you need `.sequential()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `.flatMap()` to create a single list from the `sharedFriendsIds` list that is contained in each `Contact` object from the main list `contactsList`. Please check;

```
List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
        .map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `.filter()` call is for the case when there is any `Contact` with `sharedFriendsIds == null` in the list, since that would cause `NPE` in the next line, we ought to filter those out. There are other ways to achieve that like;

### - `Optional`

```
    List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
            .flatMap(contacts -> Optional.ofNullable(contacts.getSharedFriendsIds())
                    .map(Collection::stream).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
            .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

  Where the filtering of null `sharedFriendsIds` are done in such a way that 
 they are absorbed into the `flatMap` logic as empty streams.
```

### - `emptyIfNull()`

You can include collections dependency from `apache.commons` and use `CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull` method as follows;

```
    public static <T> Stream<T> collectionAsStream(Collection<T> collection) {
        return emptyIfNull(collection).stream();
    }
```

then call this from original stream like;

```
     List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
             .map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds)
             .flatMap(Foo::collectionAsStream)
             .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also you used `.sequential` for the sort logic, I guess, you should've used `.sorted` method, since sequential is for triggering non-parallel usage, which is already the default configuration of a `Stream`.

Comment: @tsingh It's preferable to have `getSharedFriendsIds()` return an empty stream instead of `null`.

Comment: You’re calling `getSharedFriendsIds()` twice. This can be easily avoided by performing a `.map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds)` first, before the `.filter` step. You could even coerce the filter and flatmap step, e.g. `.map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds) .flatMap(list->list!=null? list.stream(): null)`, but that’s just a matter of taste…

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to use `.sequential()` here, streams are sequential by default.

```
List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
        .map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In natural order;

```
List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
        .map(Contact::getSharedFriendsIds)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

A pattern I've found very useful is to let the parent class (in this case the `Contact` class) create and return the streams of children objects (in this case the share friends ids):

```
public class Contact {

    private List<String> sharedFriendsIds;

    public Stream<String> sharedFriendsIds() {
        return sharedFriendsIds == null ? Stream.empty() : sharedFriendsIds.stream();
    }

    public List<String> getSharedFriendsIds() {
        return sharedFriendsIds;
    }
}
```

The convention is to name the method that returns the stream as the attribute being streamed. This method already contains the null-check.

Then, getting the shared friends ids for all contacts is much easier:

```
List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
        .flatMap(Contact::sharedFriendsIds)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need to use `flatMap()` in order to *flatten* the elements of the child list into a single list, otherwise you'd get a list of streams.

Note 1: you don't need to use `sequential()`, since using `stream()` on the list of contacts already returns a sequential stream.

Note 2: if you want the final list to be sorted, then you should use `sorted()` on the stream:

```
List<String> sharedContacts = contactsList.stream()
        .flatMap(Contact::sharedFriendsIds)
        .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That is nice way to clean the messy lambda notation, I also thought of that but such methods would only be used by this logic, and this was a bit excessive, if such mapping was frequent I would agree with it. Also, I think he meant to sort the resulting list, sequential usage was a mistake in his part.

Comment: @bureaquete Well, you could see the stream method as a getter. Usually, you always write getters, no matter if you're using them in your logic or not. Agree to the sequential() vs sorted() thing, I also believe the OP wanted a sorted list.